# There appears to be crossover with 'technique-identification' and 'terminology' tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-scope

The current wiki excerpt for [terminology](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) states:

> Defining, explaining or finding terms used for the tools, materials or techniques used in crafting.

[technique-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique-identification) does not currently have any description but it should be easy to infer what it is for.

[terminology](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is more encompassing by definition though. I had originally considered it to cover questions looking for a definition (or clarification) of a term or terms as seen in these

- [What does it mean to "push your values"?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/629/what-does-it-mean-to-push-your-values)
- [What is Paper Weight?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/249/what-is-paper-weight)

I could see argument favouring its current use on these types of identification questions:

- [Is there a name for sand-clay mixture?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/661/is-there-a-name-for-sand-clay-mixture)
- [What is the name of Japanese printing which uses hammered leaves on white cloth?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/trying-to-find-the-name-of-a-japanese-printing-using-leaves-on-white-cloth)

There are other examples of both cases. Some of which have both of the tags in question.

---

Is [terminology](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) being used correctly in all the above cases? As of this moment it is a tag on all of the above linked questions. Assuming that it is being used correctly (by its *current* definition I think it is) then I think [technique-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique-identification) should be dropped in favor of it.

If we think that [terminology](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is being used in a overly broad sense perhaps we need to amend the wiki except and edit the wiki for [technique-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique-identification) so their respective usages will be made clear.

I think some retagging is in order either way but I am not 100% certain what action we should take in this.

Comment: I'll think on an answer,  but in brief I believe terminology should be used for getting explanations of terms you already have "What does pushing values mean?", and not trying to find the term itself "What's this called?"

Comment: Catija had the same logic in chat. I think that is the right approach but wanted to be sure we didn't have a bias right from the get go.

Answer (score 4):

I think that they're opposites, to a degree.

[terminology](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is looking for help understanding a term or phrase you *already know* or if you want to see if that term applies to a particular project.

The first two examples above fit that well.

[something-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/something-identification) is about finding out what that terminology for a technique or tool *is*...

The second two questions fit that.

Comment: The sand clay one has an identification and terminology tag. A couple others not listed probably need retagging